# How can I define conditional subdomains in nginx config file?

Tags: nginx, subdomain, conditional-statements

How can I do (if-else) condition for subdomains?

first check >> abc.example.com

second check >> xyz.example.com

...

others (case else:) >> *.example.com  **(This part is important for me, I cannot do that)**

---

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name abc.example.com;
    ...
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xyz.example.com;
    ...
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you be more clear on what do you want?

Comment: I have installed Wordpress multisite with subdomain option. (*.example.com) refers its path. Also I control WP multisite using my web application remotely. My WP controller (web application) uses "xyz.example.com" subdomain. If users write "xyz.example.com" in browser, nginx should route this request to my web application not WP. And also other subdomains should be routed to WP.

Comment: I mean that I want to use switch-case structure for sub domains

switch (subdomain)

case "xyz":

route "a" folder


case "abc"

route "b" folder

 default (case else):
route Wordpress folder

Comment: Well, `server` blocks with `server_name` are works exactly like that. So what the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work. When I try to get blog1.example.com, this request is routed to my application not WP. And then my application returns that "page not found" error. If I delete my application's server settings in nginx configuration, WP multisite can get this request.

Comment: Look for typos. Add `default_server` flag to WP server block.

Comment: Thank you very much Alexey, your suggestion solves my problem